# Libncurses5 installation for Ubuntu 23.1

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, ncurses, ubuntu-23.10

A particular android build requires a dependency on libncurses. This was the error.

```
prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-3289846/bin/clang.real: error while loading shared      libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared 
object file: No such file or directory
12:33:20 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

1. I tried sudo apt install after enabling the universe repository. That didn't work.
2. I manually downloaded libncurses 5 from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ncurses/

After extracting and configuring, the make is failing.

This is the error after make

```
cd man && make INSTALL_PREFIX="" all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/inntot/Downloads/ncurses-5.0/man'
sh ./MKterminfo.sh ./terminfo.head ./../include/Caps ./terminfo.tail >terminfo.5
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/inntot/Downloads/ncurses-5.0/man'
cd include && make INSTALL_PREFIX="" all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/inntot/Downloads/ncurses-5.0/include'
sh ./MKhashsize.sh ./Caps >hashsize.h
AWK=mawk sh ./MKparametrized.sh ./Caps >parametrized.h
mawk -f MKterm.h.awk ./Caps > term.h
sh ./edit_cfg.sh ../include/ncurses_cfg.h term.h
** edit: HAVE_TCGETATTR
** edit: HAVE_TERMIOS_H
** edit: HAVE_TERMIO_H
** edit: NCURSES_CONST
** edit: BROKEN_LINKER
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/inntot/Downloads/ncurses-5.0/include'
cd ncurses && make INSTALL_PREFIX="" all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/inntot/Downloads/ncurses-5.0/ncurses'
sh ./base/MKlib_gen.sh "gcc -E" "mawk" <../include/curses.h | \
fgrep undef >../include/nomacros.h
o make_hash -O2  -I../ncurses -I.  -DNDEBUG -I. -I../include -I/usr/local/include       -  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DTERMINFO=\"/usr/local/share/terminfo\" -DMAIN_PROGRAM ./tinfo/comp_hash.c 
make[1]: o: No such file or directory
make[1]: [Makefile:179: make_hash] Error 127 (ignored)
sh ./tinfo/MKcaptab.awk mawk ./../include/Caps > comp_captab.c
./tinfo/MKcaptab.awk: 19: ./make_hash: not found
./tinfo/MKcaptab.awk: 20: ./make_hash: not found
sh ./tty/MKexpanded.sh "gcc -E" -I../ncurses -I.  -DNDEBUG -I. -I../include -I/usr/local /include   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DTERMINFO=\"/usr/local/share/terminfo\" > expanded.c
sh ./tinfo/MKfallback.sh  >fallback.c
mawk -f ./tinfo/MKnames.awk ./../include/Caps
cat namehdr boolnames boolfnames numnames numfnames strnames strfnames nameftr >./names.c
cat namehdr boolcodes numcodes strcodes codeftr >./codes.c
rm -f namehdr nameftr codeftr boolnames boolfnames boolcodes numnames numfnames numcodes   strnames strfnames strcodes
o make_keys -O2  -I../ncurses -I.  -DNDEBUG -I. -I../include -I/usr/local/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DTERMINFO=\"/usr/local/share/terminfo\" ./tinfo/make_keys.c 
make[1]: o: No such file or directory
make[1]: [Makefile:174: make_keys] Error 127 (ignored)
./make_keys ./tinfo/keys.list > init_keytry.h  
/bin/sh: 1: ./make_keys: not found
make[1]: *** [Makefile:169: init_keytry.h] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/inntot/Downloads/ncurses-5.0/ncurses'
make: *** [Makefile:96: all] Error 2
```

How do I add these missing files and make libncurses5 for Ubuntu 23.1?

Comment: Libncurses5 isn't available in the Ubuntu 23.10 repositories https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=mantic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libncurses.so.5 . Comment number 5 here https://bugs.gentoo.org/89772#c5 might be relevant to your second problem

Comment: That "`o make_keys`" is an error in the generated makefile, but seeing how it got that way is impossible given the lack of detail.  The suggested bug report might be relevant, but is actually too old (ncurses5 can be built from ncurses6 source, and OP does not mention what version is attempted).